# Where can I find a list of HP QC HEX Error codes

Tags: hp-quality-center, hresult

After a certain action (no conclusive evidence as to which action) Quality Center returns the following error:

```
[...] HRESULT: 0x8004dddd
```

Where the 'd' stands for any digit.

The fact that I do get such an error code might be normal. It is a way of returning error codes.

HRESULT does not only send errors. It is a way to send messages. You can find more on the [microsoft site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc704587.aspx) and on [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HRESULT).

In my example, it is an error.

A short analysis, based on the wiki article mentioned above:

```
1 |-- Failure
0 |-- Non-severe
0 |-- Microsoft-Defined (this seems weird because later on there is an indication that implies a component-specific error)
0 |-- Mapped NT status value

0 |-- X, message, not status code
0 |-- Next one from here...
0 |...
0 |...

0 |...
0 |...
0 |...
0 |...

0 |...
1 |...
0 |...
0 |-- ...To here - Decimal value: 4 - ITF (COM/OLE Interface management)

x |-- Next one from here...
x |...
x |...
x |...

x |...
x |...
x |...
x |...

x |...
x |...
x |...
x |...

x |...
x |...
x |...
x |... to here - Actual code from object - The decimal value of this part is the actual referrer I would think.
```

Remark: This might be too prudential, but because I do not know what the error is at all, I prefer not to communicate the actual error code received. This because the core of the question is not the identification of 'an error', but the quest for the source all error codes HP ALM/QC.

Also, the wiki article tells me this:

> The ITF facility code has subsequently been recycled as the range in which COM components can define their own component-specific error code.

Then we arrive back at the core of the question:

Where do I find a list of error codes defined by HP Quality Center, as implemented in the COM objects/other objects used in the HP ALM/Quality Center applications in order to troubleshoot the application more efficiently when confronted with such HRESULT messages?

FYI - already consulted the information library, but I might have missed something. All hints and tips welcomed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a DB Create/Update/Insert rights setting for a user that wasn't configured properly anymore.

Restoring the rights for the root user for the DB scheme in HP QC restored the error.

Answer (score 0):

Those error codes are no where documented in HPALM/QC documents. These are COM error codes and not specific to HP. Most of the time, reason is, your QC client dlls are not registered properly

Comment: Part of the codes should be Microsoft codes. Part is defined in the custom COM objects. The codes for the custom COM objects made by HP should be defined in their docs (if documented of course).

FYI - in the end it wasn't a mal-registered DLL. It was a DB Create/Update/Insert rights setting for a user that wasn't configured properly anymore. Only for some projects. It was kind of mysterious and it has me worrying. Thanks for the reply though!